# Create for loop to rename all columns of several data tables in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, rename

I have multiple data.tables of titled in the form of "x.y.z". I want to create a for loop that will rename the columns of each of these data.tables so that each column begins with "x.y.column's original name". Because all of the data.tables have similar columns names, when I join them I want to know which data.table the column originally came from.

I have tried use paste("x","y","z",sep=".") within setnames()/colnames() function but it doesn't recognize that the ultimate result should be a reference to an existing global variables (the data.table) and not simply a string.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "pattern" of "data.table" object names is not very clear.  Based on your description

> I have multiple data.tables of titled in the form of "x.y.z".

I created some "data.table" objects ('x1.y1.z', 'x1.y2.z',..).

```
nm1 <- ls(pattern='^x.*.')
nm1
#[1] "x1.y1.z" "x1.y2.z" "x2.y1.z" "x2.y2.z"
```

Loop through the object names ("nm1"), remove the '.z' part using `sub`, get the names of the object ("colNm"), create new names ("newNm") using `paste`, and change the column names with `setnames`

```
for(i in seq_along(nm1)){
  temp <- nm1[i]
  temp1 <- sub('..$', '', temp)
  colNm <- names(get(temp))
  newNm <- paste(temp1, colNm, sep='.')
  setnames(get(temp), colNm, newNm)
 }

 head(x1.y1.z,2)
 #   x1.y1.V1 x1.y1.V2 x1.y1.V3 x1.y1.V4
 #1:        6       13        2        7
 #2:        5        8       12        5
 head(x2.y1.z,2)
 #   x2.y1.V1 x2.y1.V2 x2.y1.V3 x2.y1.V4
 #1:       10       10       10        3
 #2:        8       18        5        5
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x1.y1.z <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 10*4, replace=TRUE),ncol=4))
x2.y1.z <-  as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 10*4, replace=TRUE), ncol=4))
x1.y2.z <-  as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 10*4, replace=TRUE), ncol=4))
x2.y2.z <-  as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 10*4, replace=TRUE), ncol=4))

setDT(x1.y1.z); setDT(x2.y1.z); setDT(x1.y2.z); setDT(x2.y2.z)
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Thank you so much!!!!

One thing though, could you explain the   temp1 <- sub('..$', '', temp)  line. I understand how the sub() function works, but I don't understand what '..$' accomplishes and why you are replacing it with ''.

Comment: @PabloBoswell `.` means just any character.  So, `..$` refers to any 2 characters at the end of the string.  Here in the example `x1.y1.z`, it will replace the `.z` by `''`, so basically you will get `x1.y1`.   Why I am replacing is because the `.z` part is common in all the files (I assumed it like that).  You don't have to replace it though).